Default iTunes Backup Password on AirWatch-Managed iOS devices
Basic question: where does (or "Does...) AirWatch set or record iPhone backup encryption passwords?
We are running an on-prem AirWatch MDM (WorkspaceOne UEM, version 23.6.0.21), iPhones are all running recent builds of iOS, and we're attempting to use an iPhone data extraction tool for records retention purposes, but we're getting prompted to enter "the iTunes backup password" as we begin the extraction process.
Yes, I'm aware this is an overall bad solution, but it is the solution the organization has decided to employ and I'm doing what I can to make it work the best it is able.
The iPhones are all enterprise-owned, DEP. We do not connect these iPhones to any computers running iTunes as a normal part of their lifecycle. Apple IDs are blocked on the phone, and we've confirmed no Apple ID is signed in to the iPhone. I've reviewed the device profile and details and the enterprise settings and haven't found anything that appears to match this.
We are reasonably certain this is not a certificate issue due to language in the extraction tool's prompts.
If I assume the extraction tool is correct in asking for this password, that would mean there is some password set by the MDM, or a password created by some process internal to the iPhone. We have tried the assigned staff's primary account password, the iPhone unlock passcode, and a variety of basic bad common passwords. I would hope the MDM would be aware of this and will have stored that password somewhere, but I haven't found that.
Or, the extraction tool could be wrong, or this message could be indication of a different issue, one the tool doesn't understand as being different.
